# FB Graph API v2.10 to v4.0 (Only for login authentication)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using FB Graph API v2.10 in react js for Login and signup functionality.
Now I'm getting a warning about upgrade api.

So, What changes needs to be done in the code if I change the v2.10 to v4.0

Comment: Probably - none. If you want to make sure, then use the information and mechanisms provided by Facebook (change log; forcing of app version for users with a role in the app via settings in the backend to test.)

Comment: I've upgraded also from v2.10 to v4.0 I've changed the api version from facebook developers settings page and updated the version in my script and it seems to work well